# Playa Position Count

Tags: playa

I'm trying to display the count/position of the entries i've selected in the Playa field, but can't seem to figure it out. For example in my Playa field I have...

**Test Post

Another Test Post

Yet Another Test Post**

But do each one of these posts have a count / position number in Playa? e.g.

**1 - Test Post

2 - Another Test Post

3 - Yet Another Test Post**

But If I was to reorder them to:

**Another Test Post

Test Post

Yet Another Test Post**

The count should still count up...

**1 - Another Test Post

2 - Test Post

3 - Yet Another Test Post**

All I can seem to output is the count of the entry which always displays "1" or the entry_id.

My code is:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="course" url_title="{segment_2}" dynamic="no"}
     {cf_course_content} {!-- Playa Field --}
          {count}
     {/cf_course_content}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: I only see the behavior you're referring to if I use `{parent:count}`. It seems to work just fine when using `{count}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In theory `{count}` should work. If it’s always being output as ‘1’ that means that `{exp:channel:entries}` (or another module tag pair you’re not telling us about?) must be parsing the tag before Playa had a chance to claim it.

Try adding your own custom var_prefix to your Playa tag pair, and apply that var_prefix to the `{count}` variable tag, as well as any other tags that are meant to be parsed by Playa:

```
{cf_course_content var_prefix="cc"}
    {cc:count}. {cc:title}
{/cf_course_content}
```

Comment: EPIC. This works. Totally missed the var_prefix parameter in the docs. Works a charm now. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try with [Pvl_Increment](https://github.com/pvledoux/Pvl_increment). It counts on every call.

Comment: Possibly... But I'm trying not to bring another add-on in to the problem.